# Executing NUnit tests through a Windows Form application with NUnit Engine

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to execute NUnit tests through a Windows Form application with NUnit Engine, but I don't understand how to set the path for the DLL where my tests are (I have already included the DLL in the references).  When I click a button, I want the tests to start; however, NUnit opens and then immediately closes without doing anything. Here's what I have:

```
namespace ATF.GUI
{
    public partial class ATF_Main : Form
    {
        TestPackage package;
        ITestEngine engine;

        public ATF_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ATF_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            package = new TestPackage(path);
            package.AddSetting("Working Directory", Environment.CurrentDirectory);

            // Prepare the engine
            engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
        }

        private void btnStartTests_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
            {
                // Execute the tests 
                XmlNode result = runner.Run(null, TestFilter.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `path` should point to the dll that includes your tests

Comment: I understand that, but how?  I tried point to the bin where it's in and I still couldn't get NUnit to run the tests.

Comment: Provide a complete path including the filename. How do you know that the tests were run or not? Do you check the content of the `result` node?

Comment: This needs to be a packaged application; having the exact file path won't work.  I'm asking how I can point the TestPackage to the tests DLL referenced in the ATF.GUI project.  I know the tests are not being run because I have a breakpoint set on them, which the debugger never reaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got a real answer to this but I figured it out myself.

```
private void ATF_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add reference to tests DLL and load it here by name
        Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.Load("Program.Tests");
        package = new TestPackage(testAssembly.Location);
        package.AddSetting("Working Directory", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    }
```

You could also add the assembly locations to a List if you have multiple test assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the test assembly to be your gui assembly. Since it has no tests, NUnit finds nothing to do. I imagine it returns an error in the result.

Somehow, your application has to be given the path of the test assembly. This can be through a command-line or a dialog of some kind. You can look at the code for nunit3-console or nunit-gui to see how it is done.

Your idea of using a referenced assembly seems a bit odd for a packaged application. Your users will need to have the source and rebuild it each time, referencing the desired test assembly. Do you really want that?

In case you do, you will need to find some way to get at that reference. Hard to do if there is nothing constant that will always be in it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing this incorrectly then - I've never set up NUnit from scratch so I'm a little lost at this stage.  I have two project within my solution ATF.GUI and ATF.Tests (a class library).  ATF.GUI is my StartUp project, and I want the button in there to automatically run ATF.Tests.  What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: The engine is set up to run tests in an assembly, given the path to that assembly. The idea is that the engine and runner can't know anything in advance about where the tests are located or what they are called, so they have to be told.

Comment: Are you already familiar with using NUnit as a package via it's own console runner or the new gui? If not, it will help to get familiar first.

Can you explain why you want the runner to reference the test assembly?

Comment: I am familiar with NUnit as a package, but not NUnit 3+.  How else would I access the test assembly from the runner if not referencing it?

Comment: Also, I need to be able to watch these tests run in the VS debugger.  What is the correct way to run NUnit so I can do that?

Comment: Think about it. NUnit does not have a reference to every user's test assembly. :-) You tell NUnit the path to the test assembly at the command-line. NUnit opens tries to load the file you specify and run the tests in it. Your code has to do the same thing. If you are using the engine, it does that for you - you just have to pass it the path to the test assembly.

Comment: To debug under NUnit, just run NUnit under the debugger. Provided your test assembly is a Debug build, you can set breakpoints, etc. in it and see what is happening. If you want to debug NUnit itself, you need to have a Debug build. You can get a debug build by building NUnit from source.